# Java Servlet: set an instance as an attribute

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I created a class User which contains several information about this user.
Like name, Session ID, etc

An instance of this class is created when a user has logged in.
Now this instance needs to be available in all jsp pages for this session.

So I thought about setting the instance as an attribute, which can be used by each jsp page.

I created an instance in the servlet in case of successful login:

```
User newUser = new User(username,request.getSession().getId());
```

in the jsp page:

```
<% 

    User user=session.getAttribute("newUser");
    %>
```

Now I have a problem with incompatible types.
The object can not be converted to User.

How do I resolve this?

Edit: It is not guaranteed, that this instance exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute` is declared to return `Object`. If you are sure that this object will be instance of `User` just use [casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

```
<% 
    User user = (User)session.getAttribute("newUser");
    //          ^^^^^^ - this means that you claim that you are sure that returned 
    //                   Object is in fact of type User (such casting is possible 
    //                   because compiler knows that like everything in Java - except
    //                   primitive types - User extends Object).
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and explaining answer!

Comment: i just realised, i can not guarantee that this instance was even created.

Comment: @user3352472 That is different problem. But maybe before casting check if `getAttribute` returned `null`. You can first store result of `getAttribute` in `Object` reference like `Object tmp = session.getAttribute("yourAttribute");` and then depending on `if (tmp==null)` create `User user` using casting or not.

Comment: `<%
/*
if(session.getAttribute("username") == null ||session.getAttribute("sessionId")== null) {
    response.sendRedirect("login.html");
}
*/
    if(session.getAttribute("newUser")==null){
        User user =new User("null","null");       
    }
    
User user=(User) session.getAttribute("newUser");
    
    
if (user.sessionId=="null" || user.name=="null"){
    response.sendRedirect("login.html");
} 
%>`

this returns an nullpointer exception. I think, because the new instance User user = new User("null","null") is not used

Comment: I would say you should post this as separate question since possibility of some value being null has very little to do with your original question.